# Software like Synergy that also works with windows

Tags: multiple-monitors

I'm using Synergy to control both a desktop and a laptop with a single set of mouse/keyboard. Unfortunately my desktop monitor is rather small (to programmer standards). I'd like to drag windows from my desktop and carry them to the laptop

Is there any software that can do this?

Comment: Interesting question... Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/321618/where-can-i-ask-questions-that-arent-programming-questions

Comment: @sigjuice Vnc does not allow what I want. I could run a clone of one monitor in the other, or maybe extend my first desktop to the other. But I could not say, move windows like I would normaly do across the plastic edge of the monitor

Comment: Maybe "How can I use a second pc to extend my desktop" would be a better question for this, and yes, it is not programming related, actually belongs on superuser (at least serverfault)

Comment: this sounds kind of like what citrix does

Answer (score 2):

You appear to be trying to move a running program from one machine to another.  Not generally possible, and certainly not on any Windows based system that I know of.

***update***
You can't (generally) use your laptop screen as a second screen for your desktop, though it's quite likely you could use your monitor as an additional screen from your laptop.

Short version - buy a bigger screen (or better two) for your desktop computer.  You will save more time and effort (ergo: money for your employers) in the space of a few months than trying to hack around with multiple computers to do what could be trivially accomplished with a decent gfx card and a couple of $100 screens.

Comment: He probably does not need to use the laptop as a computer, just as a monitor would suffice.

Comment: Kinda sounds like it *could* be made to work with an X server or maybe some fancy RDC trickery...

Comment: I don't really need the process to move from one machine to another, just the window bound to the process. Much like a small vnc for every application or something like that

Comment: Yes, you can use your laptop as a second screen for your desktop. Check the link in Shane's answer...

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean somethine like [VistaMax](http://www.maxivista.com/)?  It's not free tho.

Comment: funky, I wonder what the overhead for pushing those pixel across the local network is.

Comment: I have not idea how it works, it may be similar to Micosoft's RDC implemenation where they send GDI commands to reduce bandwidth?